# WPF equivalent of jQuery's class selector

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

**Question**: In [jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp), we select certain elements by using [class selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_class.asp), and then change a property (color, size, text, etc.) of those elements. Do we have something similar in `WPF`?

**Motivation**: In some cases, we use same `TextChanged(...)` event, say, `MyTextBoxes_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)` for all `TextBoxes` on a WPF Window (or Page). But what if we want to use that same event not for all but only certain `TextBoxes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do the equivalent in wpf is to set the style explicitly on the element.

You give a style a key:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="ExplicitStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter .....
```

And then reference that on the specific textbox:

```
 <TextBox Style="{StaticResourece ExplicitStyle}"
```

Style is a dependency property in WPF which means it can have only one value meaning no cascading direct equivalent.

You may inherit one style from another using BasedOn

```
 <Style x:Key="ExtendedStyle" BasedOn="ExplicitStyle"
```

And a style with no key or the same as the type of the control is the default style applied to all controls of that type.

There are other mechanisms you might want to consider.

For example, events are often routed events which tunnel and bubble. Meaning you may handle all unhandled events of a particular type at a parent level like say for the window.

Resources have scope so you can potentially merge in a style with matching key and different settings at a lower scope and override a parent.

Also worth mentioning datatemplating. It's common to build out UI based on data rather than create UI and present a model to it as you would with MVC.
And of course the usercontrol or just a chunk of xaml you create from a datatemplate can have it's own styles and values set.

CSS ( especially with mixins ) is more flexible but wpf scores in other areas.

As an aside.
You mentioned Page.

It's usual to work with UserControls rather than Page(s) unless you're building a "wizard" style of process where the user cycles through several steps of input or an XBAP. The reason being Frame and Page come at a memory overhead whilst ContentControl and UserControl do not. You don't have to style away the navigation buttons on a contentcontrol neither.